# Python Selection sort with nested while loop

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I know that I can sort arrays using selection sort with a nested for loop as follows:

```
def selection_sort(arr):
 for k in range(len(arr)):
      cur = k
      for i in range(cur, len(arr)):
           if arr[cur] > arr[i]:
                cur = i
           temp = arr[cur]
           arr[cur] = arr[k]
           arr[k] = temp
```

But can this be done with a while loop nested in a for loop? I'm curious because I saw it mentioned that the syntax for this selection sort function could be similar to an insertion sort function, such as the one that follows:

```
def insertion_sort(arr):
 for k in range(1, len(arr)):
      cur = arr[k]
      j = k
      while j > 0 and arr[j-1] > cur:
           arr[j] = arr[j-1]
           j = j - 1
      arr[j] = cur
```

Am I overlooking something simple? It has been a while since I've used python, but it just seems simpler to use a for loop instead of a while loop, doesn't it? Nevertheless, I'm confused on how it can be done.

Comment: _Anything_ that can be done with a `for` loop, can be done with a `while` loop, too (it's a theorem).

Comment: Your for-loops simply iterate over the range of indices, this can be done very simply with a while loop: `i = 0; while i < len(arr): <do some stuff> i += 1`

Comment: But you should use the for-loop.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, if I could pick your brain to check my work, I have: for k in range(len(arr)):                      cur = k                                                                                                                               i = 0                                                                                                                               while i < len(arr):                                                                                                          temp = arr[cur] arr[cur] = arr[k] arr[k] = temp i +=1

Comment: I know you're only doing this for educational purposes, but don't use selection sort for anything real.  It's [terrible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ns4TPTC8whw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your code is wrong.You can try to put the array your function.
array = [1, 4, 7, 2, 0, 4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 3, 4]

Then, if you use for loop

```
def selectSort_for(list):
    if list != None:
        for i in range(len(list)):
            min = i
            for j in range(i + 1, len(list)):
                if list[min] > list[j]:
                    min = j
            if min != i:
                list[min], list[i] = list[i], list[min]

    return list
```

if you use while, the code as following

```
def selectSort_while(list):
    if list != None:
        for i in range(len(list)):
            min = i
            x = i
            while x + 1 < len(list):
                x += 1
                j = x
                if list[min] > list[j]:
                    min = j
            if min != i:
                list[min], list[i] = list[i], list[min]

    return list
```

Oh, your code is wrong because you miss the equal condition.By the way,

```
temp = arr[cur]
arr[cur] = arr[k]
arr[k] = temp
```

It's not a pythonic styling.

Your code may be should like this

```
def selection_sort(arr):
    for k in range(len(arr)):
        cur = k
        for i in range(cur+1, len(arr)):
           if arr[cur] > arr[i]:
                cur = i

        if cur != k:
           arr[cur], arr[k] = arr[k], arr[cur]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going more with python style:

```
def sel_sort(arr):
 for k in range(len(arr)):
    sublist = arr[k:len(arr)+1]
    min_index = sublist.index(min(sublist))
    sublist[min_index], sublist[0] = sublist[0], sublist[min_index]
    arr = arr[0:k]+sublist
 return arr
print sel_sort([5,1,4,7,5,2,8,1,4,6,9,3])
```

There is actually two nested loop but the second loop is done by the built in function min().
The output is [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

as almost, python has fewer code line than others.

Answer (score 0):

While loop nested in a for loop -

```
def selectionsort(l):
    i = 0
    while i < len(l) - 1 :
        for j in range(i+1 , len(l)):
            if l[i] > l[j]:
                (l[i], l[j]) = (l[j], l[i])
        i += 1
    return(l)

selectionsort([74, 32, 89, 55, 21, 64])
```

The output is [21, 32, 55, 64, 74, 89]